# alguien sabe porque mi query me jala un ultimo registro

Tags: mysql

Les comparto mi consulta

```
$empresa = "SELECT e.Empresa, a.Nombre,l.sitio, a.correo, g.Fecha_Resguardo 
            FROM guard g INNER JOIN Empresa e ON g.Empresa = e.Id_Empresa 
            INNER JOIN Empleado a ON g.Empleado = a.Id_Empleado 
            INNER JOIN Lugar l ON a.Departamento = l.id  
            WHERE id_resg = (SELECT MAX(No_Resguardo) FROM conceptResg)";
```

Comment: Qué obtienes con esa consulta? Qué debería salir? Qué datos hay en la tabla (o muestra unos datos de prueba para entender lo que quieres). Por favor, edita tu pregunta con la información relevante.

Comment: es la condición en tu where que le hace seleccionar una sola

Comment: pues debe de jalar registros de una tabla hace un recorrido donde me trae resultados dependiendo del id de el usuario pero al ultimo me trae un 0 que deberia de salir

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, ordena tu pregunta. Que datos trae? que datos tiene que traer? que tiene tu tabla? asi como esta, es imposible darte una respuesta